# Penrose diagram and coordinate transformation

Tags: metric-tensor, relativity, causality

I am looking at the Minkowski line element in spherical coordinates
$$ \mathrm{d}s^2 = - \mathrm{d}t^2 + \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2(\theta) \mathrm{d}\phi^2$$ and want to perform a coordinate transformation
$$ u = t - r \, , \, v = t + r$$
which leads to 
$$ \mathrm{d}s^2 = - \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}v + \frac{(v-u)^2}{4} ( \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \mathrm{d}\phi^2).$$

Apparently $u$ can be identified as the outgoing light ray and $v$ can be identified as the incoming light ray in the Penrose diagram. How can one get to that conclusion?

Just by looking at the new coordinates and setting $u = 0$ you get $t=r$ which is a diagonal line that corresponds to outgoing light. Likewise you get $t=-r$ if you set $v=0$ which corresponds to incoming light. What is the deeper physical meaning behind setting the coordinates to $0$ and finding the lightrays starting from there? Usually, I would look at $\mathrm{d}s^2 = 0$ and find the lightrays starting from there but that didn't really help me.